# Why can't the Polynomial Ring be a Field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I'm currently studying Polynomial Rings, but I can't figure out why they are Rings, not Fields. In the definition of a Field, a Set builds a Commutative Group with Addition and Multiplication. This implies an inverse multiple for every Element in the Set.

The book doesn't elaborate on this, however. I don't understand why a Polynomial Ring couldn't have an inverse multiplicative for every element (at least in the Whole numbers, and it's already given that it has a neutral element). Could somebody please explain why this can't be so?

Comment: Take polynomial $f(x) = x$ and check that it can't have inverse.

Comment: The favourite question of my students at this point: "Why isn't $1/x$ a polynomial?"   :-)

Comment: @Augusti Roig: The definition of a polynomial is that the deg(x) has to be greater than one, right? So 1/x is clearly not a polynomial. Feel free to correct that if it's wrong xD

Comment: @SB: Well, a simpler way of looking at it is that a polynomial has to be continuous everywhere; 1/x clearly isn't.

Comment: @SB. Greater or equal than zero.

Comment: You might find it useful to look at the field of fractions of a polynomial ring. By looking at this and comparing the differences, I think it will be illuminating for you. Plus it will get you thinking in the direction of localization, which is a good direction to be thinking. :)

Comment: @Soul: Minor nit: It's not true that a field is a commutative group with multiplication, because $0$ has no inverse. Rather, a field is a ring in which the **nonzero** elements form a group under multiplication.

Comment: @Ｊ.Ｍ., polynomials over arbitrary fields aren't "continuous" anywhere. In fact, you can use $x$ just as a mark, and not ever consider the polynomial as a function. Yes, for $\mathbb{R}[x]$ this makes sense, but don't get boxed in.

Comment: @vonbrand I remember when my abstract algebra teacher taught me formal sums, I was like "okay what are you saying? Is this a sum or not a sum?"

Comment: @falagar I think your example is bad. When f(x) = x then isn't x also the inverse of f(x)?

Answer (score 218, accepted):

**Hint** $\rm\quad\rm  x \, f(x) = 1 \,$ in $\,\rm R[x]\ \Rightarrow \ 0 = 1 \, $ in $\,\rm R, \,  $  by evaluating at $\rm\ x = 0 $

**Remark** $\ $ This has a very instructive **universal** interpretation: if $\rm\, x\,$ is a unit in $\rm\, R[x]\,$ then so too is every $\rm\, R$-algebra element $\rm\, r,\,$ as follows by evaluating $\ \rm x \ f(x) = 1 \ $ at $\rm\ x = r\,.\,$ Therefore to present a counterexample it suffices to exhibit any nonunit in any $\rm R$-algebra. $ $ A natural choice is the nonunit $\,\rm 0\in R,\,$ which yields the above proof.

Comment: This is a good answer! The type of answer I really want to remember  when my students ask this question! So much better than the degree argument! In short, I love it!!!

Comment: I agree--this is extremely elegant, exactly what you want in a proof.  I upvoted it!

Comment: @BillDubuque Read this wishing to understand it, but isn’t this peculiar? “it suffices to exhibit _”. Please fill me in on what you mean by “exhibit”? Do you mean that it suffices to show that a non-identity does X?

Comment: @Jon To "exhibit" a counterexample to: every $\rm R$-algebra element is a unit, it suffices to show there exists a nonunit in some $\rm R$-algebra

Comment: @BillDubuque I just read the following [question and answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/58424/25805). I got curious on the following: Why can we construct a field in $F_p$ but we can't in $R$?

Answer (score 22):

For $F[x]$ to be a field, you need to show there is an inverse for each element that isn't 0. Now $x \in F[x]$, and clearly $x \ne 0$ (considered as a polynomial). But if you multiply $x$ by any non-zero polynomial, the result will always contain $x$ or higher powers, so it has no inverse.

Comment: So what if I consider $ \Bbb{Z}_n[x]$?

Comment: @ManjoyDas, again, what is the inverse of $x$? Show a *polynomial* $p(x)$ over $\mathbb{Z}_n$ such that $x p(x) = 1$.

Comment: I wanted a general proof that such $ p(x)$ does not exist in case of $ \mathbb{Z}_n[x]$ rather than finding an arbitrary example.

Comment: @ManjoyDas, "a general proof" can't exist, as there ate polynomials (the constant ones) that *do* have inverses. Any polynomial of degree 1 or more can't have an inverse.

Answer (score 17):

Because by definition, the only polynomial that can have a negative degree is $0$, which is defined to have a degree of $-\infty$. Non-zero constants have degree $0$.  You then have the degree equation: $\deg (fg) = \deg (f) + \deg (g)$  for any polynomials $f,g$.  By inspection, any polynomial of degree $n \geq 1$ would need as an inverse a polynomial of degree $-n$, which does not exist (i.e. what Agusti Roig said!) The set you want does exist, however: it is called the *field of rational functions*, and is precisely the set of ratios of polynomials.  It is constructed the same way that the field of rational numbers is from the ring of integers.

Comment: The degree equation only works for polynomial rings over domains.

Answer (score 6):

Consider $\mathbb{C}[x]$ the ring of polynomials with coefficients from $\mathbb{C}$. This is an example of polynomial ring which is not a field, because $x$ has no multiplicative inverse.

Answer (score 5):

The units of $D[x]$ are exactly the units of $D$, when $D$ is a domain.

Comment: While this is true when $D$ is an integral
domain, it fails for general commutative rings
(but still $D[X]$ is never a field).

Answer (score 0):

Let $R$ be a field. If $f$ is a polynomial whose degree is at least 1 in $R[x]$, then $f$ cannot have an inverse.

For if $f(x)g(x) = 1$, where $f$ and $g$ are polynomials whose degree is at least 1 in $R[x]$, then the leading coefficient of $g$ would have to be $0$, which is
impossible.

Comment: Well. If $F=\Bbb{Z}_4$, then we have 
$$(1+2x)(1+2x)=1+4x+4x^2=1.$$

Comment: may be just restrict R to be a field. my answer was not for any ring .. :) im wrong