# For $x+y \in \mathbb{Q}[x,y]$, show that $\langle x+y\rangle$ is maximal among all principal ideals and show that it is not maximal among all ideals

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

This is my approach:

So, I know that $\langle x+y\rangle$ consists of all polynomials with $x+y$ as a factor in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$. I believe it must be maximal among all principal ideals because $x+y$ is prime in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$, thus rendering $\langle x+y\rangle$ a prime ideal meaning it must be maximal. 
I know my logic is flawed, but I am not sure where to go from here. Furthermore, I am not too sure how to show that it is not maximal among all other ideals.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The easy way to prove that $\langle x+y \rangle$ is not maximal among all ideals is to find a larger proper ideal, which won't be principal.  Can you spot an obvious candidate to try?

Answer (score 2):

$I=\left<x+y\right>$ is maximal amongst proper principal ideals, as $x+y$ is irreducible.
A principal ideal strictly containing $I$ would be generated by a proper factor
of $x+y$, and as $x+y$ is irreducible, this ideal could only be the whole ring.

Geometrically, 
the ideal $\left<x+y\right>$ corresponds to the line $x+y=0$ in the affine plane.
Maximal ideals correspond to points in the affine plane (well, at least
if the ground field is algebraically closed). So pick a point on this line,
say $(0,0)$ and let $J$ be the ideal of polynomials vanishing there,
so $J=\left<x,y\right>$. Then $J$ is a proper ideal strictly containing $I$.

Comment: Is there a way to prove this without using geometric properties?

Comment: Well, one can show that $J$ contains $I$ purely algebraically. But heeding the geometry shows one where to look for a suitable $J$. When studying polynomial rings like this it's always wise to keep the geometry in mind. @flutterbug98

Answer (score 0):

Let $\,D=\Bbb Q[y].\,$ $\,(x\!+\!y) \subseteq D[x]\,$ is prime ([thus](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2983648/242) $\rm\color{#c00}{irred}$) [since](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/13336/242) $\,Q := D[x]/(x\!+\!y) \cong D\,$ is a *domain*.

So $\,(z) \supsetneq (x\!+\!y) \iff z\mid x\!+\!y\,$ *properly* $\color{#c00}\iff z\mid 1\iff (z) = (1),\,$ by [contains = divides](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/39649/242)

And $(x+y)$ is not maximal [since](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1071706/242) its quotient $\,Q \cong \Bbb Q[y]\,$ [is not a *field*.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2523/242)