# If $F$ is a field show that $F[x]$ is not a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that $ax=1$ has a solution in $F$ so that every element must be a unit but then I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Can you think of an inverse of the polynomial $x$?\

Comment: That has a solution for every x in F, but that is not really the same x as the indeterminate of the polynomial ring.

Answer (score 5):

It's obvious that $F[x]/(x) $ is isomorphic to $F$, and hence $(x)$ is a non trivial proper ideal of $F[x]$, and hence $F[x]$ can't be a field.

(Note that there are other trivial ways of doing this problem, as mentioned in the comments, and an answer above, but I thought of doing this problem in a bit different way, just for fun.)

Comment: Very neat proof ! :)

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** $\rm\rm\,\  x \; f(x) = 1 \,$ in $\rm\ F[x]\, \Rightarrow\, 0 = 1 \, $ in $\rm F \, $  by evaluating at $\rm\ x = 0.\ $

If you know the *universal* (mapping) property of the polynomial ring then you may find it instructive to interpret the above from that viewpoint [(see here)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2523/242).

Answer (score 4):

Can you find a polynomial in $p \in F[x]$ such that $p(x)\cdot x = 1$?  Why not?