# Show $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb R[X]$ not isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, group-isomorphism

Why are the rings $\mathbb{R}$  and      $\mathbb{R}[ x ]$   not isomorphic to eachother ?

Think it might have to do with multiplicative inverses but I'm not sure.

Comment: However they are isomorphic as additive groups (and even as $\Bbb Q$-vector spaces).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right: the element "$x$" has no multiplicative inverse, that is there is no polynomial $p(x)$ such that $x\cdot p(x)=1$.

Comment: And there is a [slick yet insightful way](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2523/242) to prove that $\,x\,$ is not invertible.

Answer (score 2):

Well $\Bbb R$ is a field while $\Bbb R[X]$ is not.

Question: if a ring is ring-isomorphic to a field, is it necessary a field?