# Prove (or disprove) that a polynomial ring modulo an ideal is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I have the following problem I'm working on: Prove or disprove that $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/\langle{x^2+y^2}\rangle$ is a field.

I know that this amounts to asking whether or not the polynomial $x^2 + y^2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ - if it is irreducible, then the ideal generated by the polynomial $x^2 + y^2$ is maximal in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$, yielding that the quotient ring $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/\langle{x^2+y^2}\rangle$ is a field, whereas if it is reducible, the quotient ring has zero divisors and is not even an integral domain ($\Rightarrow$ it cannot be a field).

To this point, suppose it is in fact reducible. Then it must be the product of two linear polynomials in the variables $x$ and $y$

$\Rightarrow$ $x^2 + y^2 = (ax + by + c)(dx + ey + f)$ , where $a,b,c,d,e,f \in \mathbb{R}$

$\Rightarrow$ $x^2 + y^2 = adx^2 + dexy + afx + bdxy + bey^2 + bfy + cdx + cey + cf$

$\Rightarrow$ $ad = 1, be = 1, ae+bd = 0, af+cd = 0, bf + ce = 0, cf=0$.

From the resulting equations, one can try and get a contradiction to $x^2 + y^2$ being a product of two linear polynomials in the variables $x$ and $y$, or try and get a solution for the real coefficients that will make $x^2 + y^2$ factor.

I tried to achieve the former. If $cf = 0$, then $c = 0$ or $f = 0$ (using that $\mathbb{R}$ is an integral domain). If $c = 0$ and $f \neq 0$, then $bf = 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $b = 0$, yielding a contradiction to $be = 1$. If $c \neq 0$ and $f = 0$, $ce = 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $e = 0$, yielding a contradiction to $be = 1$. However, in the case that both $c = 0$ and $f = 0$, I'm not able to reach such a contradiction. Is my logic so far sound? How can I refine my argument from here?

Thanks!

Comment: Your problem is not tantamount to showing that $x^2+y^2$ is irreducible. In fact, no principal ideal can be maximal in the polynomial ring $k[x_1,\cdots, x_n]$ over the field $k$ for any $n\ge 2$.

Comment: $x^2+y^2$ is indeed irreducible in $\mathbf R[x,y]$, and this shows the ideal $(x^2+y^2)$ is prime since we're in a U.F.D. Hence the quotient is an integral domain.

Comment: Actually, $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/\langle{x^2+y^2}\rangle \cong \mathbb{C}[t]$ by $x \mapsto t, y \mapsto it$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to show (ir)reducibility because we work over a polynomial ring in strictly more than one variable.

Observe that $$(X^2 + Y^2) \subsetneq (X,Y)$$

and hence your ideal is not maximal. It follows that the quotient ring is not a field.

Comment: Hi EpsilonDelta. Could you explain why this proper inclusion holds? How can one see that $(X,Y)$ is not in fact the entire ring $\R[x,y]$ ? I'm trying to unpack the fact that our ideal is not maximal.

Comment: @mich See my answer for an simple way via *evaluation* (vs. more common degree arguments), and compare [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2514/why-cant-the-polynomial-ring-be-a-field/2523#2523)

Comment: For example, $X\notin (X^2+Y^2)$ (use a degree argument).

Comment: And $(X,Y)$ is not the entire ring because it does not contain constants.

Answer (score 2):

If suffices to show that $x$ is nonzero and noninvertible in the quotient ring $R$

If $x$ is invertible in $R\,$ then in $\Bbb R[x,y]\!:\ xf = 1 +(x^2\!+\!y^2)g\,$ so $\,0 = 1\,$ via eval at $\,x = 0 = y$

Similarly if $\,x=0\,$ in $R\,$ then in $\Bbb R[x,y]$ we have

$\ x = (x^2\!+\!y^2)f(x,y)  \overset{\large y\ =\ x}\Rightarrow\ x = 2x^2f(x,x)$  $\overset{{\rm cancel}\  x} \Rightarrow 1 = 2xf(x,x)\,$ so $\,1 = 0\ $ via eval at $\,x=0$