# On the $\mathbb{K}(x_1, ..., x_n)$ field

Tags: abstract-algebra

My manual is asking to prove that $\mathbb{K}(x_1, ..., x_n)$ with regards to the addition and multiplication operations is a field, which is the field of quotient field of $\mathbb{K}[x_1, ..., x_n]$.

Firstly I don't understand well the different between $\mathbb{K}(x_1, ..., x_n)$ and $\mathbb{K}[x_1, ..., x_n]$. I know that $\mathbb{K}[x_1, ..., x_n]$ is the field of polynomials with *n* indeterminates and coefficients over $\mathbb{K}$.

By definition a field is a commutative ring with unity in which every non-zero element is a unit.

Comment: The ring of polynomials is not a field (What would be any inverse of $x_1$ for example ?)

Comment: The elements of $\mathbb K(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ are "fractions" $p/q$ where $p,q\in\mathbb K[x_1,\ldots x_n]$, $q\ne 0$ and equality of fractions is given by $p/q=r/s\Leftrightarrow ps=qr$. The map $p\mapsto p/1$ is an injective map of $\mathbb K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ into $\mathbb K(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$. This is the same construction as making up $\mathbb Q$ from $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2523/242) is a nice conceptual way to see why $x$ is not invertible in $R[x],\,$ one that is often overlooked.